# Change Row/Column hierarchy dynamically when using flex in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to make a component responsive for mobile. The initial way I've created the component was to start with a Row, which will contain IMG and TEXT content as children. Then, the TEXT content itself will be inside a Column which contains title and description. So that's Column inside a Row and it would look something like this.
[image: Column inside Rows]

When in mobile resolution, I want the description text to come below the image and title. Something like this, except the description takes the empty space on the left too. With my current structure its not possible since description is part of the Column inside the Row. It doesn't take the empty space to the left. I can only think of doing this changing the Row/Column hierarchy in JS which would again affect the desktop resolution.

[image: Rows inside Column]

Is there a way to achieve this dynamically using CSS without changing the react component structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **You can achieve this by using `grid` instead**

Pay attention to the `grid-template-areas`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.picture { grid-area: picture; }
.title { grid-area: title; }
.content { grid-area: content; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'picture title'
    'picture content ';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-areas:
      'picture title'
      'content content';
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="picture">Picture</div>
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```